# Update Cell dimension based on contained HTML elements (and accordingly update location of ports )

Tags: jointjs

I am evaluating JointJS for a custom model where the entity is drawn using HTML elements. And I want to:
- Resize the Cell based on HTML content (dynamically update size and port location based on HTML update)
- Position ports against certain HTML elements (based on a business logic).

For clarity (diagram below):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**resize:**

you need to track the changes on the checkbox list and then resize the element manualy, e.g.:

```
var handleResize = function() {
    element1.prop('size/height', element1.prop('size/height') + 30)
}
```

**ports:**

In JointJS v1.0 there is an API for manipulation with ports and theirs positions. You can add a port to any shape, for example to a position x:10, y:10 (relatively to the element origin)

```
 element1.addPort({
        args: {
            x: 10, y: 10
        },
        attrs: {
            circle: {fill: 'red', stroke: '#31d0c6', 'stroke-width': 3, r: 10, magnet: true}
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vtalas/ahk2no15/

**Docs:**

http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html#dia.Element.ports